# How to divide an array into 3 parts with the sum of each part roughly equal

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an arranged array and I want to divide it into 3 parts so that their sum are closest         to each other.

```
Ex: I have this array:

    10, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5

so it'll be divided into 3 part like:

    p1 {10,8} sum = 18
    p2 {8,7,6} sum = 21
    p3 {6,6,5} sum = 17
```

Comment: I did in dividing a array in 2 parts, It worked. But I haven't any idea for deviding it into 3 yet

Comment: Wouldn't `10+7=17`, `8+6+6=20` and `8+6+5=19` be a better fit?

Comment: It's better, but I want to group them with an order, in this case it from i=0 to i=7

Comment: based on your example i think you want to split your array, keeping the original order. also the sum of the splitted sections must be alsmost the same value of the previous/next value.
the additional information might be needed: 
- Which decimals are use (0-10) of (0-100) of (0-endless)...
- How many decimals are used?

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand your mind.

Comment: This is a problem in my program, simulate the Fano cryptographic algorithm in base 3, so I need to split the probility into 3 part..

Comment: do you have to keep elements in order? If not, you are in NP-Hard realm... I mean, can the first element and last element in the array be in the fame part of the array?

Comment: Is this homework?  I seem to recall something like this my senior year. ;)

Comment: Check the modified code below. I've tested it with various values in array(arranged in descending order) and also with different value for no. of parts(3,4,5...) and got good results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original poster already has a working solution (noted in comments) to split the array into two parts with equal sums; call this `split2`. The three-part version can be constructed using `split2`.

1. Add to the array a new number equal to one-third of the sum of the original numbers.
2. Split the array into two parts using `split2`.
3. One part has the number that was added; remove it.
4. Split the other part into two using `split2`.

Comment: Nice algorithm, but there is a problem with it in case when totalSum of all elements in source array equals to zero. In this case `split2` function call make no sense, since it'll split exactly all original array and new "fake" element.

Comment: @Hit Interesting point. In practice, the case when totalSum is zero is trivial: you have the original set and two empty sets. Depending on how `split2` works, this trivial solution might not be obtained, though, if the approach I described is followed blindly.

Answer (score 2):

This is like [`two-Partition`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) problem which is NP-Hard but not in strong sense, you can have an O(nK) algorithm for it where K is size of your input sum, See [`pseudo polynomial time algorithm for subset sum`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution), Also See my answer for [`divide-list-in-two-parts-that-their-sum-closest-to-each-other`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479479/divide-list-in-two-parts-that-their-sum-closest-to-each-other/4479714#4479714), but in your case you should just add another dimension to process it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
int total = 0, partSum = 0, partIndex = 0;
int noOfParts = 3; //Initialize the no. of parts
int[] input = { 10, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5 };
int[] result = new int[noOfParts]; //Initialize result array with no. of locations equal to no. of parts, to store partSums
foreach (int i in input) //Calculate the total of input array values
{
    total += i;
}
int threshold = (total / noOfParts) - (total / input.Length) / 2; //Calculate a minimum threshold value for partSum
for (int j = input.Length - 1; j > -1; j--)
{
    partSum += input[j]; //Add array values to partSum incrementally
    if (partSum >= threshold) //If partSum reaches the threshold value, add it to result[] and reset partSum  
    {
        result[partIndex] = partSum;
        partIndex += 1;
        partSum = 0;
        continue;
    }
}
if (partIndex < noOfParts) //If no. of parts in result[] is less than the no. of parts required, add the remaining partSum value
{
    result[partIndex] = partSum;
}
Array.Reverse(result);
foreach (int k in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
Console.Read();
```

I've tested this with various values in array(arranged in descending order) and also with different value for no. of parts(3,4,5...) and got good results.

Comment: Why we have this code?
`int threshold = (total / parts)-(total / array.Length) / 2;`

Comment: It is just to calculate a minimum threshold value so that the three sums will be greater than the threshold value. It is calculated by dividing the total of array by the no. of parts(in this case, 56/3 = 18.66 rounded to 18) and subtracting that with half of the average((56/8)/2 = 7/2 = 3.5 rounded to 3). So the full equation in this case is (56/3)-(56/8)/2 = 15.

Answer (score 1):

```
// calculate total
total = 0;
for(i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
   total += array[i];
}

// partition
n_partitions = 3;
current_partition = 1;
subtotal = array[0];
for(i = 1; i != size; ++i) {
   if(subtotal + array[i] > total / n_partitions) {
      // start new partition;
      current_partition++;
      subtotal = array[i];
   } else {
      // push to current partition
      subtotal += array[i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated with code:

The approach I suggest is as follows (with code below):

- Create data structures (Collections etc) to represent the number of output parts that you need (in your example 3)
- Sort the input array in descending order.
- Iterate through the elements of the input array and for each value:

  - pick an output part to place the value in (this should be the output part currently with the lowest overall sum..)
  - add the value to the selected output part

With the above logic, you will always be adding to the output part with the lowest overall value (which will help to keep the parts of similar overall value).

(in the code sample below I have skipped the array sorting step as your example is already sorted)

Code:

```
        // the input array
        int[] inputArray = new int[] { 10, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5 };

        // the number of parts you want
        int numberOfOutputParts = 3;

        // create the part structures
        List<Part> listOfParts = new List<Part>();

        for(int i =0; i < numberOfOutputParts; i++)
        {
            listOfParts.Add(new Part());
        }

        // iterate through each input value
        foreach (int value in inputArray)
        {
            // find the part with the lowest sum
            int? lowestSumFoundSoFar = null;
            Part lowestValuePartSoFar = null;

            foreach(Part partToCheck in listOfParts)
            {
                if (lowestSumFoundSoFar == null || partToCheck.CurrentSum < lowestSumFoundSoFar)
                {
                    lowestSumFoundSoFar = partToCheck.CurrentSum;
                    lowestValuePartSoFar = partToCheck;
                }
            }

            // add the value to that Part
            lowestValuePartSoFar.AddValue(value);
        }
```

The code for the Part class used above (although you could use something better is as follows):

```
public class Part
{
    public List<int> Values
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int CurrentSum
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructpr
    /// </summary>
    public Part()
    {
        Values = new List<int>();
    }

    public void AddValue(int value)
    {
        Values.Add(value);
        CurrentSum += value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @vuonghien: Congratulation you have solved your problem. Why don't you vote for the attendees ^^. Long source code....

Answer (score 0):

Could you try my sample, this may help you

My Algorithm:
1/ Calculate avg value of the array numbers by the number of output array (exp:value=3 in your post)

2/ Sum the array numbers until the Sum has min gap compare to the avg value (calculated in 1/)

3/ Do step 2 until you go to the end of the array numbers

I using C# 3.5 to test

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ArrayList inputValue = new ArrayList();
        int avgValue = 0;
        bool isFinish = false;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            #region Init data
            isFinish = false;
            avgValue = 0;
            inputValue.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            //assum you input valid number without space and in desc sorting order 
            string[] arrNumber = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int numberOfBreak = 3;
            int record = Convert.ToInt32(arrNumber[0]);//update the record with the maximum value of the array numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < arrNumber.Length; i++)
            {
                inputValue.Add(Convert.ToInt32(arrNumber[i]));
            }

            foreach (object obj in inputValue)
            {
                avgValue += (int)obj;
            }
            avgValue = avgValue / numberOfBreak;
            #endregion
            int lastIndex = 0;
            while (!isFinish)
            {
                int index = GetIndex(lastIndex);
                string sResult = "";
                for (int i = lastIndex; i <= index; i++)
                {
                    sResult += inputValue[i].ToString() + "-";
                }
                listBox1.Items.Add(sResult);
                if (index + 1 < inputValue.Count)
                {
                    lastIndex = index + 1;
                }
                sResult = "";
            }
        }

        private int GetIndex(int startIndex)
        {
            int index = -1;
            int gap1 = Math.Abs(avgValue - (int)inputValue[startIndex]);
            int tempSum = (int)inputValue[startIndex];
            if (startIndex < inputValue.Count - 1)
            {

                int gap2 = 0;
                while (gap1 > gap2 && !isFinish)
                {
                    for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < inputValue.Count; i++)
                    {
                        tempSum += (int)inputValue[i];

                        gap2 = Math.Abs(avgValue - tempSum);
                        if (gap2 <= gap1)
                        {
                            gap1 = gap2;
                            gap2 = 0;
                            index = i;
                            if (startIndex <= inputValue.Count - 1)
                            {
                                startIndex += 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isFinish = true;
                            }
                            if (startIndex == inputValue.Count - 1)
                            {
                                index = startIndex;
                                isFinish = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            index = i - 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            else if (startIndex == inputValue.Count - 1)
            {
                index = startIndex;
                isFinish = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isFinish = true;
            }
            return index;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see my sample is bad. It's too long =))