# Recursively divide a list that each iteration divides into two parts to get the closest sum overall

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, dynamic-programming, approximation, partition-problem

Given a list of numbers L = { a1, a2, a3, a4, ... , aN}

The problem is to divide this **L** into two parts, not just once but recursively until it becomes atomic. The main idea is like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479479/divide-list-in-two-parts-that-their-sum-closest-to-each-other) but adding the recursion thing.

*(added: June 9)* **For example,** if we have L = {10, 20, 1, 2} *(edited: June 10)* the solution might be, first, divide it to {10, 1, 2} and {20}, then divide the former into {1, 2} and {10}, keep going with {1, 2} to {1}, {2}. Now all the members of L are now **atomic** unable to be divided anymore.

After being divided, it should look like a binary tree of some sort.

Let's say it look like this..

```
  (a1 a2 a3 a4)
       /\
      /  \
     /    \
    /      \
 (a1 a2) (a3 a4)
   /\      /\
  /  \    /  \
(a1)(a2)(a3)(a4)
```

At each node the similarity function is

```
abs( sum(left_child) - sum(right_child) ) / sum(itself)
```

**I want to find an "optimized" way to divide the list (create the tree) according to the "summation" of this function.** Note that at the top level this value might have more impact than the lower ones, so weights should be provided.

```
weight(level) * abs( sum(left_child) - sum(right_child) ) / sum(itself)
```

let **level** is the level of this node in the binary tree.

I think it is possible to solve this using dynamic programming with the time complexity of O(2^N). However, this solution seems to be too slow for me. Anyone has any better solutions ?

Both optimization and approximation are welcome as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check my answer, i updated it to make it fit for your instance of problem.

Comment: @AshkanKzme I did check it but I found it doesn't get to my point because I want to **minimize the summation of the similarity function** (mentioned above) .. the solution you proposed will optimize for each node but **not** for the entire tree .. btw. thanks a lot for fast reply

Comment: @AshkanKzme did you delete your answer ? or I did something wrong again ? I shocked when I refreshed and found nothing ..

Comment: I deleted the answer since it didn't provide a correct solution to your probelm. and I kinda think that you cannot get a better running time of O(2^N) with the weight constraint you have, it makes the problem extremely difficult to solve!

Comment: is it absolutely necessary to make it recursively? i believe there're many ways to get the result you want in O(n) time, without using recursion

Comment: @EmilianoSorbello my point is not to be using recursion to solve this problem. I only stated it for the sake of explanation ... I think you can propose any kind of algorithm that solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

An O(n) time complexity but really inaccurate approach would be:

```
def distance(a, b):
    return abs(a - b)

def balancedSlice(myList):

    total = sum(myList)
    a = 0        #a, b are the sum's of each slice
    b = total
    dist = distance(a, b) # current distance between slices
    for i in range (len(myList)):
        a += myList[i]
        b -= myList[i]
        if dist <= distance(a, b):
            return myList[:i],myList[i:] #list sliced "from 0 to before i" and "from i to end"
        dist = distance(a, b)
```

Another, a bit more accurate but not perfect, greedy algorithm in O(n log n):

```
def balancedSlice(myList):
    list1 = list()
    list2 = list()
    myList = list(myList) #skip if you can destroy the original list.
    myList.sort() # O(n log n)
    while myList:
        item = myList.pop()
        if sum(list1) <= sum(list2):
            list1.append(item)
        else:
            list2.append(item)
    return list1, list2
```

However, as stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), this is an NP problem so if your list is big enough and you can tolerate imperfect results, you should stick to something like this greedy algorithm.

Comment: I got you now .. the thing is the order of elements in the list is not important .. I can shuffle them and should get the same result. One more thing .. you also have to guarantee that the "overall" distance will be minimized according to the function I gave .. sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: so basically you have a bunch of items and want to pack em in 2 bags (lists, sets, etc) so that they are as balanced as possible, right?

Comment: not just 2 bags because each bag might have its own sub-bags see the binary tree above :D