# Divide list into two equal parts algorithm

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, computation-theory, partition-problem, data-partitioning

> *Related questions:*
>
> - [Algorithm to Divide a list of numbers into 2 equal sum lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890171/algorithm-to-divide-a-list-of-numbers-into-2-equal-sum-lists)
> - [divide list in two parts that their sum closest to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479479/divide-list-in-two-parts-that-their-sum-closest-to-each-other)

Let's assume I have a list, which contains exactly `2k` elements. Now, I'm willing to split it into two parts, where each part has a length of `k` while trying to make the **sum of the parts as equal as possible.**

*Quick example:*
`[3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1]` might be splitted to `[1, 4, 3] and [1, 2, 4]` and the sum difference will be `1`

Now - if the parts can have arbitrary lengths, this is a variation of the [**Partition problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) and we know that's it's weakly `NP-Complete.`

> But does the restriction about splitting the list **into equal parts** (let's say it's always `k` and `2k`) make this problem solvable in polynomial time? Any proofs to that (or a proof scheme for the fact that it's still `NP`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still `NP` complete.  Proof by reduction of `PP` (your full variation of the Partition problem) to `QPP` (equal parts partition problem):

Take an arbitrary list of length `k` plus additional `k` elements all valued as zero.

We need to find the best performing partition in terms of `PP`.  Let us find one using an algorithm for `QPP` and forget about all the additional `k` zero elements.  Shifting zeroes around cannot affect this or any competing partition, so this is still one of the best performing unrestricted partitions of the arbitrary list of length `k`.